# Error while receiving image array from the Child's folder Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to receive an array of images with title from my Child's folder to the another offertableview which is connected by button from the detailViewController, but unfortunately I keep getting an error. Below I attached images of my firebase data structure and my mainstoryboard screenshot.

For the first table view I have a list of the restaurants and upon selecting a cell it transfers to the detail view controller which lists all the details of the restaurant (for that I've created a model of my restaurant) in that detailVC I have a button connected to the offerstableview which lists all the offers of that particular restaurant.

When I click to the button it transfers to the offers table view which results to the application shut down due to the error.

my offers tableview code:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var offerImageArray = [String]()
var titleArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchBars()
}

func fetchBars(){

    ref.child("Paris").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "offers")
            let dict = imageSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let imageUrl = dict["offer_image"] as? String
            let titleUrl = dict["offer_title"] as? String
            self.offerImageArray = [imageUrl! as String]
            self.titleArray = [titleUrl! as String]
        }
    })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return offerImageArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OfferCell", for: indexPath) as! OffersTableViewCell

    cell.offerImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.offerImageArray[indexPath.row]))
    cell.titleLabel.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
           return cell
}
```

**Xcode error:**

> 2017-08-16 10:26:33.652 Applic[1174] 
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase
>   Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set
>   the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
>   2017-08-16 10:26:33.826 Applic[1174] 
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search
>   Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled. 2017-08-16 10:26:33.828
>   Applic[1174]  [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase
>   Analytics enabled fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping
>   an Optional value

[image: NewFirbaseStructure]

Comment: Add print(snapshot) before for loop to see what you get?

Comment: issue is in loop you are using can you share project file ? so I can try to Correct for loop you are using here

Comment: @iOSGeek https://github.com/didayo/Project

Comment: @user1000 I keep getting the same message :(

Comment: Please comment the for loop and then tell me the result of print(snapshot)

Comment: not able to run your project . you need to update full folder including files

Comment: @iOSGeek please try this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwHF

Comment: Link says not found

Comment: @iOSGeek https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwHFfcVPE2wdNHptaHQzRm13cEU

Comment: I am able to display images on  offer table but I can't find any offer_title in snapshot

Comment: @iOSGeek is it possible to send me the project with dispaying offer image, please?

Comment: yes I will update on drive

Comment: @iOSGeek thank you ;) waiting for update

Comment: its Done . Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SDWebImage


class OffersTableVC: UITableViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
   var offerImageArray = [String]()
    var titleArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchBars()
    }

    func fetchBars(){

        Database.database().reference().child("paris").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            print("Main Snapshot is \(snapshot)")

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "offers")



                if let snapDict = imageSnap.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    let dictKeys = [String](snapDict.keys)
                    print(dictKeys)
                    let dictValues = [AnyObject](snapDict.values)
                    print(dictValues)


                    for each in dictValues{
                        let imageUrl = each["offer_image"] as? String
                        print(imageUrl!)
                        self.offerImageArray.append(imageUrl!)

                    }
                    self.tableView.dataSource = self
                    self.tableView.delegate = self
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }





//                let dict = imageSnap.value as! [String: Any]
//                let imageUrl = dict["offer_image"] as? String
//                let titleUrl = dict["offer_title"] as? String
//                self.offerImageArray = [imageUrl! as String]
//                self.titleArray = [titleUrl! as String]
            }
        })

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return offerImageArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OfferCell", for: indexPath) as! OffersTableViewCell

        cell.offerImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.offerImageArray[indexPath.row]))
//        cell.titleLabel.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
               return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much again ) But also I have a favour) Can you please delete my name above all codes please? )

Comment: its Done :) Sorry for that

Comment: Thaaank you  very much :)

Comment: Happy to Help :)

Comment: Hey) I found one big issue :( Basically when I press the offer of one Bar in the tableview controller it displays all the offers including the other bar's offers :/ For example the black and yellow bars offers are the second bar's offers and the images with soup and cutting board are the images of the first bar :( I would appreciate if you can help me with it)

Comment: let me see the structure of your firebase again I will tell you what you can do . may need to do little modification in structure or we will try code with your present structure

Comment: Done!! but can you tell me what is Aktau or Paris I had done Code for aktau is this place name ? I am statically providing aktau in my code you can do it dynamically as it will be required I am attaching code in drive link

Comment: "aktau" is correct) Thankk you ) maybe its better to update code here?

Comment: I had done changes in appDelegate , MainTableVc, and your offerTableVc. So should I post code or project download and notify me I will delete the link after that

Comment: I guess then its better to send the link to download the project)

Comment: I posted a comment just add those lines or I will post link for project just need to add these few lines and its done

Answer (score 0):

1) in Appdelegate.swift add selectedBarname as follow

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var selectedBarName = String()
```

2) MainTableVc Add following code

After declaration of Class

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

in prepareForSegue

```
if segue.identifier == "DetailView", let bar = selectedBar{
            appDelegate.selectedBarName = bar.barName
```

3) OfferTableVc

now just call this function and Done but do not call your fetchBars now just getOffers

```
func getOffers() {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("aktau")
        databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "bar_name").queryEqual(toValue: self.appDelegate.selectedBarName).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {
            print("not found)")

        } else {
            print(snapshot.value!)
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "offers")
                if let snapDict = imageSnap.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

                    let dictValues = [AnyObject](snapDict.values)


                    for each in dictValues{
                        let imageUrl = each["offer_image"] as? String
                        print(imageUrl!)
                        self.offerImageArray.append(imageUrl!)

                    }
                    self.tableView.dataSource = self
                    self.tableView.delegate = self
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }

            }


        }
    })
}
```

Comment: its working ) Thaaank yoou very much I really appreciate your help:) U saved me)

Comment: Welcome, Happy to Help :)